# Secure CrudRepository.save() to specific owner

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-rest

I'm using spring-data-rest with spring-security.

Suppose I have this model:

```
public class Item {
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    private final String description;
    private final String username;
}
```

Its repository:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Long> {
    @Override
    @PostFilter("filterObject.username == principal.username")
    Iterable<Item> findAll();
}
```

findAll() method worked, it returns only items which belong to username.

**Question 1**: How to override method `save()` to restrict user saves item only if it belong to him?

```
@Override
<S extends Item> S save(S s);
```

**Question 2**: Currently I use many @PostFilter for each method like `findAll` and `findOne`... How to restrict whole repository items to user at once, by one annotation, at repo level?
I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29692158/6445037), but also want to ask for more pretty solution.

Comment: 1. Use event handler instead: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events

Comment: I cant find event for `find` action. Does it support event like BeforeFind AfterFind?

Comment: No, it doesn't. If you need to implement security in your project see this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/#react-and-spring-data-rest-part-5

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. I finally did it like `@PreAuthorize(#entityName?username == principal?.username")`